# ZipArchive Create Entry using Zip File to memory stream

Tags: c#, zip

I am using Zip Archive to create a zip folder with various files and subfolders and returning it as a memory stream like so.

```
 public MemoryStream CreateAZipFolder(){

var stMarged = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
 stMarged.Position = 0;
     using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
   string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Applications\folder");
                    foreach (var fileName in fileEntries)
                    {

                        zip.CreateEntryFromFile(fileName, "Applications/folder/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName),
                            CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    }
    ZipArchiveEntry batchEntry = zip.CreateEntry("mybatchFile.bat");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(batchEntry.Open()))
                    {
                        writer.Write(batchFile);
                    }

                    //Add the xml file to zip folder
                    ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry("nCounterConfig.xml");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                    {
                       writer.Write(xdoc.OuterXml);
                    }


                }

                zipStream.Position = 0;
                return zipStream;
```

I would like to add a directory with sub directories and files to this memory stream. I found that ZipFile has a method "CreateFromDirectory" which would be ideal except it requires a paramater for an output folder the method also does not have a return type. How can i zip all the files and subfolders in a directory and add them to my memory stream using ZipFile?

something like this

```
 zip.CreateEntry(ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(
                            @"C:\morefilestozip\", "",
                            CompressionLevel.Fastest, true));
```

Comment: "_I would like to add a directory with sub directories and files to this memory stream._" I am completely confused about your question. Your code in the question already demonstrates how to do this. So, what are you asking for? What's the problem?

Comment: the directory i want to zip using ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory has many subfolders. I would like to use the method instead of iterating through each folder and then add to the zipstream.

Comment: Ah, okay. Look up the documentation for `Directory.GetFiles` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. It has an overload featuring a `SearchOption` parameter that allows you to get/enumerate files in a directory recursively (i.e., getting the files in sub directories as well) Using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` will probably be less costly, performance-wise...